# Express middleware with different methods (PUT/POST) on a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.route('/ad/apply')
        .put(adController.applyAd)
        .post(notificationController.addNotification)
```

Above route won't work, I got error 404 not found if I added in 3rd line like that. How do I do PUT and then POST? if it's both PUT I can just do

```
app.route('/ad/apply')
        .put(adController.applyAd, notificationController.addNotification)
```

Comment: you can have one post, one put etc. for the same url

Comment: are your handler defined? what if you comment out the 2nd line (put), does the post work?

Comment: You need to debug it - put a breakpoint in the put or post handler and check if you can stop there - if so - check why you return 404.

Comment: @chenop I don't even know the syntax is valid

Comment: @DrNio then I can't use that as middleware? obviously addNotification cant be a PUT it is a POST

Comment: to be honest i got a bit confused. how do you get 404 ?are you sure you use POST or PUT?Maybe you are trying the url in your browser and since you don't have a .get route you see the 404 ?

Comment: also which version of nodejs and express are you using ? the syntax looks valid to me since by definition is `app.METHOD(path, callback [, callback ...])` - so you have an array of callbacks, or you seperate them by commas as you did.

Answer (score 0):

> Above route won't work, I got error 404 not found if I added in 3rd line like that.

To reproduce your scenario locally, I tried the following code. It didnt have any specific issues with line alignment.

```
'use strict';

let http = require('http');
let express = require('express');

let app = express();

let server = http.createServer(app);

const PORT = 8888;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up at ${PORT}`);

  app.route('/').put((req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send({
      msg: 'hello from PUT'
    });
  }).post((req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send({
      msg: 'hello from POST'
    });
  });

});
```

May be, 404 is because of some other routes taking precedence over this based on the order of declaration.

Comment: @JamieAden Yes it did.